# A Meta question about Meta. On accepting answers/which answer to accept

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

The main thrust of the question is that I saw in chat an 'official answer reached' statement involving a question on meta.  I'm no moderator, but I do ask questions here.

Do I just accept the highest voted answer, the one I think is most correct/reasonable(not necessarily the one I agree with the most), etc?

Comment: Offtopic !!goto metametaaskubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I got from a moderator in chat was highest voted answer as a general rule of thumb.

I think it might be more relevant as a general rule for non-moderators like myself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, on meta, it is not really necessary to accept an answer. We don't even have the "Accepted rate" metric on meta.

But, if you are focused on accepting an answer, you may choose the highest voted answer if it is a discussion type question, especially if the discussion is meant to arrive at a consensus from the community.

Possibly related question on Meta.SO: [When do you accept an answer on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85095/when-do-you-accept-an-answer-on-meta)

Comment: Definitely related, but I think I was trying to go somewhere different with it.  +1 for the reference though